# Read through Firebase snapshot - Android

Tags: android

I am having some issues with the Android version of my app. I completed the iOS version and am working on the Android data part. After I get the the snapshot in Swift, I can simply say something like this:

```
myList.addObject((snapshot.value["num"] as? String)!)
```

Then I have a nice list of of the numbers I need.

So far with Android it isn't that simple. Here is my how my data is structured and what I am looking for.

```
staffNUM
     --staff
         --12345677
            -- num:112234
         --2345689
            -- num:090909
         --44445677
            -- num:999234
         --6665689
            -- num:888673
```

I can't change the way the data is created since the app for iOS is already being used.

Here is the question:

I have a reference to my database, which works.

```
  mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Here is how I am calling the database after:

```
  mDatabase.child("staffNUM/staff").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    Log.d("Snap", "" + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                    StaffNum staffNum = dataSnapshot.getValue(StaffNum.class);
                    } else {
                       // something else happens
                      }
```

My results in the snapshot are:

> D/Snap: {staff={12345677={num=112234},{2345689 ={num= 090909},{2345689 ={num= 090909}, {44445677={num= 999234}, {6665689 ={num= 888673}}

What is the best way to parse that data? I just need a list like I did in Swift to use in the app.

Edit:

Here is the class I added

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class StaffNum {
      public String num

      public StaffNUM() {}

      public StaffNUM(String num) {
        this.num = num;
      }
      @Exclude
      public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
         HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
         result.put("num", num);
         return results;
      }
    }
```

If I call Log.d("num: ","" + staffNUM.num);
I still get

> D/num:: null

Comment: Define a POJO for the data you have to parse. Once you define the Pojo class which matches your data, just do this line `Staff staff = snapshot.getValue(Staff.class);` . Reference - https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: @sha I updated the current issues. I already had your answer implanted but it didn't work the first time I tried it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Staff POJO with the fields that you need from your Firebase structure

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Staff staff = d.getValue(Staff.class);
            Log.d("Snap", "num: " + staff.getNum());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't adding a getter. I must still be stuck in iOS.